# how to display image in Qlabel in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, qlabel

I am trying to display an image in pyqt5 by using an label but when i click the button the image is not showing up. and the gui is getting close instead.

here is my code

```
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication ,QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage,QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class anyname(QDialog):
        def __init__(self):
                        super(anyname,self).__init__()
                        loadUi('image.ui',self)
                        self.SHOW.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
                        self.TEXT.setText('kindly press show button')

        @pyqtSlot()     
        def onClicked(self):
                img= cv2.imread('E:/photoshopimages/images.png')
                self.displayImage(img,1)
                cv2.destroyAllwindows()
        def displayImage(self, img,window=1):
                qformat = QImage.Format_Indexed8

                if len(img.shape) == 3:
                        if (img.shape[2]) == 4:
                                qformat=QImage.Format_RGBA888

                        else:
                                qformat=QImage.Format_RGB888
                img =QImage(img, img.shape[1],img.shape[0],qformat)
                img =img.rgbSwapped()
                self.imgLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))
                self.imgLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | Qtcore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
window=anyname()
window.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("exiting")
```

Comment: improve your indentation and remove `cv2.destroyAllwindows()`

Comment: @eyllanesc still not working. i removed ``` cv2.destroyAllwindows()```

Comment: read the duplicate question and answer